# Prove regarding ordering of natural numbers

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

I started reading Terence Tao - Analysis 1 for fun. I just finished chapter 1 but I'm still having trouble with one exercise. I can proof it but only with knowledge that hasen't been defined yet by the author.

The problem is: $a < b$ if and only if $a++ \leq b$

I was able to do $\leftarrow$ but still can't figure the other direction out. Could someone please provide a hint?

My start: Let $a, b\in \mathbb{N}$ with $a < b$, that means $b = a+c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$...

edit: a++ means a+1, the author defined addition based on increment.

Comment: What is $a + + \leq b?$

Comment: what do you mean by $a++ \le b$?

Comment: I edited my post: it means $a+1 \leq b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a < b$ and suppose if possible $a+1 > b$. If $b = a+c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have $a+c < a+1$ which means $c < 1$ which is contradiction.